# IOS - dim parent view when add a color picker subview

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-messenger

[Picker color view][1]

[image]

I would like to make a view (like the one in screenshot below). When the picker view shows up, the screen behind is faded  just like the photo. 
Thank for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's not hard to achieve this.

First, create a UIView called `ColorPickerView` and add some buttons with custom image to it(in your example, circles with different color).Then add the `Cancel` button so the user can remove(using removeFromSuperView) `ColorPickerView` by tapping it. Finally, add a UILabel to represent the title of `ColorPickerView`.

When the `ColorPickerView` show up, you should add a view on your mainPageView(Screen behind `ColorPickerView`). Let's call it `blurView`. Set the backgroundColor of `blurView` to black, alpha to 0.3(your choice). Similarly, when `ColorPickerView` is going to be removed, you should remove the `blurView` also.

You can remove `blurView` in the action of `Cancel` button.

Comment: Consider accept my answer if you have no further questions :)